# How to check Linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How the following equation is not linear?

$$ \frac {dy}{dx}+xy=xy^2$$

is it not linear because its not in the below given form?

$$ \frac {dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: You just answered your own question.  $xy^{2}$ is not a function of only x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** It is not of the right form, so it is not linear. But even nicer, it is separable.

**Added:** Alternately, since you are interested in a linear equation, divide everything by $y^2$. The right substitution will get you a linear equation. You will lose the solution $y=0$.

Comment: Can it be converted to linear form?

Comment: I am sure it can. One can cheat, solve the equation, and use the solution to decide on how to transform to linear form. Or one can make a clever guess.

Comment: I should add a little. Divide everything by $y^2$. You will see that $\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$ looks an awful lot like the derivative of $\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: Sorry but i think Iam still doing it wrong, dividing by $$\frac 1y^2$$ gives $$\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=x-\frac {x}{y}$$ ?

Comment: Let $z=\frac{1}{y}$. Then $\frac{dz}{dx}=-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$. We get $-\frac{dz}{dx}=x-xz$. This gives $\frac{dz}{dx}-xz=-x$. Nicely linear! Don't trust my calculation, I am weak on minus signs.

Comment: Thanks for awesome help :)

Comment: @Andre : Ever met someone who told you : Oh I am strong on minus signs! I wait for that day, still.

Answer (score 3):

Precisely because of that. A differential equation is called linear when it can be re-written as 
$$
\mathcal L(y) = y_0
$$
where $\mathcal L(y)$ is a *linear differential operator*, i.e. 
$$
\mathcal L(\alpha y_1 + y_2) = \alpha \mathcal L(y_1) + \mathcal (y_2) 
$$
for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $y_1, y_2$ are sufficiently differentiable functions for your operator to work. Think of $\mathcal L$ as some function of $y$ and possibly $x$ (i.e. $y(x)$, <- that $x$). The function $y_0$ here would be something not depending on $y$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is equivalent to:
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} + xy - x{y^2} = 0.$$
The left-hand side of the equation is not a linear function of $y$ and its derivative.